# Angular: How to detect route changes in current component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, angular-ui-router

I want to detect a route from the current component and tried something like that. But it is triggered on every route starts and ends. Instead of this, how can I detect **only** the route changes when routes from this `DetailsComponent`?

```
export class DetailsComponent {

    constructor(private router: Router) {

        this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            }

            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            }
        });

   }
}
```

I need to get the url while navigation from this `DetailsComponent` and make an operation if the url is not `/employees`.

Comment: Anybody else have knowledge about this routing issue?

Comment: Is it not possible to detect route changes **only for the current component**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your events continue to be detected, is because you are not unsubscribing from `router.events` when your `DetailsComponent` is destroyed.

If you simply unsubscribe, it should work for you:

```js
export class DetailsComponent {
  private sub = this.router.events
    .pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart),
      map(event => event as NavigationStart),  // appease typescript
      filter(event => event.url !== '/employees')
    )
    .subscribe(
      event => console.log('[DetailsComponent] NOT going to "/employees"!', event)
    );

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    console.log('>> STOP listening to events for DetailsComponent');
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66705251?file=src/app/one/one.component.ts) example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I realized it and unsubscribed as you suggested. On the other hand, I cannot get the previous url using `this.router` or `Location`. Is it possible? I just need to get the previos url before coming to this Details page.